# Disable mouse over Visual Studio bottom tabs to popup

Tags: visual-studio-2010

OS: WinXP
VS2010

The default setting for Visual Studio tabs is when mouse over it, the window will popup. This is annoying sometimes when I don't want the window displayed. Is there any way to disable this auto popup and just display when I click it? Please advise, thanks.

[image]

Comment: This isn't normal behavior, never seen it on my machines.  Document what add-ins you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

In native visual studio there is no way do disable this behaviour.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx for detailed information. 
Regard the note: "Tool windows that have Auto Hide enabled may temporarily slide into view when the window has focus. To hide the window again, select an item outside of the current window. When the window loses focus, it slides back out of view." 
Seems they know, that it's a annoying behaviour, but don't offer a sensible solution. Microsoft...